# Jupiter JUnit skipping a test once Apache EntityUtils.toString is called

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, junit-jupiter

Running into an issue where test calls a get request to a local server using Apache HttpClient in a unit test. The test works if I use the native java Scanner to decode the response but if I use EntityUtils.toString(), junit ignores the test once it hits that line of code which is bizarre because I can see the print out of every line before it.

```
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

HttpEntity entity = reponse.getEntity();
System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity); // skips test here
```

Version info: gradle 7.5.1, Java 17, junit-jupiter 5.9.1, Apache HttpClient 4.5.13

Comment: share your code and setup

Comment: updated the post with the code. it’s difficult to post everything because it’s on a vpn machine where stackoverflow is blocked

Comment: Did you debug what is happening in that line?

Comment: I added a debug line but then the debugger is not activating there even when it activates at the line before